# recyclerview loading menu from firebase returns blank activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am creating a category menu that takes you to another sub menu. loading its content based on the category number. the first category activity shows the content of the database but the second activity doesn't.

laoding from firebase and binding it using firebase-ui.
The result is blank page.

i am using Android studio 3.3
Gradle 28

Error shows:

```
I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path
at void com.example.assus.orderline.SplashScreen.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SplashScreen.java:18)
```

where line 18 is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
```

My FoodList Class:

```
package com.example.assus.orderline;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.assus.orderline.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.assus.orderline.Model.Food;
import com.example.assus.orderline.ViewHolder.FoodViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference food;


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    String categoryId = "";

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);

        //init firebase
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        food = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Food");


        //Load Menu
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //get Home.class intent here
        if(getIntent() != null ){
            categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
            if(!categoryId.isEmpty()){
                loadFoodList(categoryId);
            }

        }//end if


    }

    private void loadFoodList(String categoryId) {

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>
                (Food.class, R.layout.food_item,
                        FoodViewHolder.class,
                        food.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryId)) //like select * from Food where menuId =
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {

                viewHolder.txtFoodName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageFoodView);

                final Food local = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + local.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        //set adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // put your code here...

    }



}//end class
```

The FoodViewHolder class:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.assus.orderline.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.assus.orderline.R;

public class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView txtFoodName;
    public ImageView imageFoodView;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;



    public FoodViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtFoodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        imageFoodView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);

    }
}
```

Here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //add library database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'

    //add library
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
}
```

This is my Logcat window content after debugging

```
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.assus.orderline-dIoMN-0TD-2sxqP-GVySGA==/split_lib_slice_5_a
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void com.example.assus.orderline.SplashScreen.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SplashScreen.java:18)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7009)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.711 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7000)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.712 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline I/zygote:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
2019-02-13 12:16:33.712 10402-10402/com.example.assus.orderline
```

Screenshot:
[Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9NZm.jpg)

[Blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNsWa.jpg)

Comment: Does your `SplashScreen` class extend `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Yes. It does. same thing appears for SignIn class in same setContentView line